# Passing multiple id_token_hint to the custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

With reference to the following page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/id-token-hint

Is there a way to send multiple JWT tokens to a custom policy so that they all can be validated in the policy?

Reason I ask is as per above page, the JWT token must be sent as 'id_token_hint' query param which is reserved. Can this be extended to read a second JWT say 'id_token_hint2' from the query string and validate in GetClaims profile.

Use case:

1. I want to send the current signed-in users' ID token in id_token_hint param.
2. I want to also send a custom JWT in another param say id_token_hint2 param and validate it similar to #1 (but against my metadata endpoint).

Regards,
Dipesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. This follows the OIDC specification for id token hint.

I don’t see why 1&2 can’t be a single JWT. 1 will also be against your metadata endpoint, as is 2.

Comment: Thanks Jas, I ended up including the users' ID (sub) in my custom JWT. This way I dont need the ID token anymore.